# Create table with multiple columns

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

Can anyone help me? I want to create a table with 5 columns and 8 rows in Xcode. Then i need to fill in table with data from Database. I'm working on an application for Ipad. I've search a lot for this problems but no result. Can anyone give an example for this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple problem when you'll think of it. Since your columns is fixed, you will need to subclass UITableViewCell and create a custom UITableViewCell with 5 columns (or UIViews or whatever you need in those columns). Then simply use your custom UITableViewCell within the table and you can have as many rows as you want.

[Tutorial for creating custom cells](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/)

You can use core data and NSFetchedResultsController for populating data (will need to map table indexpath to the core data manually since you have 5 objects in 1 row).

[Also, see the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643093/xcode-setting-up-multiple-uitableview-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **UICollectionView**. Here's a tutorial in which it is used to create a *grid*:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

You can replace the code for adding images with the code for putting in your data from database.