# Making a Custom Navigation, the best way?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to do a similar menu to the app for iPhone that has USA Today, I thought about making a UIViewController within 2 UIView dividing screen, on the left side the buttons and right hand side a UITableView, am I correct or is there another way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Your way will be correct one. Show the buttons while selecting more option and hide left buttons, once a button option has been selected.

Answer (score 1):

There are many open source libraries for these types of control online.

https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

just to name a few

Answer (score 0):

It could be an illusion portrayed by GFX/photoshop design, in which the developer would only need one view and just insert an image to make that illusion. This would then allow for IBActions to be assigned to each text label.

Comment: maybe is how you say, but also can do it natively, without use images? o I'm very lost?

Comment: I'm not sure...Simon provided some good links regarding the "sideview" appearance. My bet would to try messing around with your original technique of using two separate UIViews in a View Controller.

Comment: My technique is a bad practice? The problem with Simon's links is that just are made with a column, In this moment my app have a side menu but I need two columns in my menu.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643093/xcode-setting-up-multiple-uitableview-columns This includes everything regarding column views. It looks like you'll have to create your own cells and with their own designs.